# Anti Aliasing Fonts in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am developing in Xamarin Forms and i am using XAML and is great powerfull.

When i emulate on android, all fonts don't look so good. It seems to be a anti aliasing problem. I really don't know.

[image]

Any tips will be apreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe this has anything to do with Xamarin.Forms, but rather the emulator itself, and how it renders.

Comment: Agree  with @MatthewRegul you should test in a real device.